# R lmer equivalent in python with two random effects and no fixed effects

Tags: python, r, lme4, smf, statmodels

I'm trying to convert an `lmer` R code to python and I'm having a hard time getting the same results. The data has 2 random effects
Here is the R code:

```
library(openxlsx)
library(lme4)

xx <- read.xlsx("test_data.xlsx")
print(summary(lmer(Val ~ (1 | R1) + (1 | R2) + (1 | R1:R2), data = xx)))
```

the output of this is

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Val ~ (1 | R1) + (1 | R2) + (1 | R1:R2)
   Data: xx

REML criterion at convergence: 184.3

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.52934 -0.77882 -0.09979  0.69857  2.32918 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 R1:R2    (Intercept)   0.0     0.000  
 R1       (Intercept) 733.9    27.090  
 R2       (Intercept)   0.0     0.000  
 Residual              19.9     4.461  
Number of obs: 30, groups:  R1:R2, 6; R1, 3; R2, 2

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   122.17      15.66     7.8
```

for python equivalent I'm using `statsmodels`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

xx = pd.read_excel("test_data.xlsx")
xx['group'] = 1

formula = "Val ~ 1"
vcf = {"R1": "0 + C(R1)", "R2": "0 + C(R2)"} 
model = sm.MixedLM.from_formula(formula, data=xx, groups=xx["group"], vc_formula=vcf,re_formula="~1+R1:R2")
result = model.fit()
# Print the summary of the model
print(result.summary())
```

The output for this is

```
         Mixed Linear Model Regression Results
========================================================
Model:              MixedLM Dependent Variable: Val     
No. Observations:   30      Method:             REML    
No. Groups:         1       Scale:              19.6936 
Min. group size:    30      Log-Likelihood:     -92.4598
Max. group size:    30      Converged:          No      
Mean group size:    30.0                                
--------------------------------------------------------
                   Coef.  Std.Err. z P>|z| [0.025 0.975]
--------------------------------------------------------
Intercept         121.678                               
Group Var          19.694                               
Group x R1:R2 Cov   0.000                               
R1:R2 Var           0.578                               
R1 Var            789.843  201.169                      
R2 Var              0.217                               
========================================================
```

The intercept and the var value are not similar. Is there a way to get the exact same output? how should the python `vc_formula` and `re_formula` be set to be equivalent to the R formula?

test_data.xlsx:

```
R1  R2  Val
1   1   123
1   1   114
1   1   119
1   1   119
1   1   113
1   2   122
1   2   115
1   2   119
1   2   129
1   2   113
2   1   95
2   1   96
2   1   100
2   1   94
2   1   99
2   2   95
2   2   93
2   2   102
2   2   96
2   2   100
3   1   151
3   1   144
3   1   149
3   1   154
3   1   155
3   2   147
3   2   145
3   2   149
3   2   157
3   2   158
```